# Select the ids from an array of jquery elements

Tags: jquery, arrays

With the following jquery statement I select an array of elements:

```
selectedSupplierIds = $('.supplierListCheckbox:checked');
```

I need to select the ids from these elements. Can I do this without creating an array and pushing the ids in a for loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get an array of anything based on your object selection...in this case your just want the `.id` property from each, like this:

```
var arr = $('.supplierListCheckbox:checked').map(function() { 
            return this.id; 
          }).get();
```